# Uploading image to web service using alamofire and swifty json returns error failure

Tags: ios, swift4, alamofire

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire_SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController , UINavigationControllerDelegate , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

var Image = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func ChosePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    let getimage = UIImagePickerController()
    getimage.delegate = self
    getimage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    getimage.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(getimage, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func Uploading(_ sender: Any) {


    let requestURL = UU
    let param = [
        "S1" : "7f3a92a2-9c25-4b96-ba20-489c6412e36f",
        "S2" : "F/EogECr4Z1GwtVQANHq",
        "S3" : "EE0009BB-CF91-4ECB-AB5C-3F9BA6CA0A61" ,
        "Base64Image" : self.Image ,
        "FileId" : "bd535daf-21c6-4b4b-98d5-7042f7789aab",
        "Extension" : "jpeg" ,
        "CommentId" : "c1f57f35-1c81-4b4e-a1b5-18e14eb761e7"
    ]
    let header = [
        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let mess = response.result.value!
            print(mess)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage?
            let data : Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!
            let Ima = data.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
            self.Image = Ima
            print(self.Image)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

> SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library
>   2018-08-31 18:04:56.890342-0700 background[2690:63834] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2868 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library
>   {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass image in to string parameter you have to convert image into `base64EncodedString`

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.Image)!
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

And pass `strBase64` into parameter value for `Base64Image` key in your case.

Comment: im convert it as this :  let data : Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.2)!
        let Ima = data.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
        self.Image = Ima

Comment: @HebaGH change options of  `endLineWithCarriageReturn ` to `lineLength64Characters `

Comment: return me the same error  line 2868 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library

Comment: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: Ask to your backend developer for this - May be it's helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139524/messagethere-was-an-error-processing-the-request-stacktrace-exception

Comment: in backend its correct .. i think the error in alamofire or SwiftyJson becuase its work with other programmer